# codeblock colors

Tags: listings, code

Hello this is the codeblock code I currently use

```
\lstset{
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},  
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breakatwhitespace=false,      
  breaklines=true,                
  captionpos=b,                    
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen}, 
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=single,                   
  keepspaces=true,             
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},      
  language=c++,                 
  numbers=none,                
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{blue}, 
  rulecolor=\color{black},        
  showspaces=false,               
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,                 
  stepnumber=5,                  
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},    
  tabsize=3,                      
  title=\lstname                
}
```

In the code of cp-algorithm
https://cp-algorithms.com/sequences/longest_increasing_subsequence.html

How can I change the number color to red?
And also is it possible to change the function color?
(Using lstlisting)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution strongly adapted to your concrete problem. I tried to stick to the style used in the code on the web site you linked. You have to add digits and function names manually to highlight them in the desired color.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings} % Display code / shell commands
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\lstset{  
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},  
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,   
    breakatwhitespace=false,  
    captionpos=b, 
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen}, 
    extendedchars=true,              
    frame=single, 
    keepspaces=true,  
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},      
    numbers=none,                
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{blue}, 
    rulecolor=\color{black},        
    showspaces=false,               
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                 
    stepnumber=5, 
    tabsize=3,                      
    title=\lstname  
    breaklines=true,
    emph={lis},                   % emphasize the function lis ...
    emphstyle={\color{purple}},   % ... and take purple as emph-color
    literate=                     % color single literates 0, -1 and 1e9
    {0}{{{\color{red}0}}}1
    {-1}{{{\color{red}-1}}}1
    {1e9}{{{\color{red}1e9}}}1,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
int lis(vector<int> const& a) {
    int n = a.size();
    const int INF = 1e9;
    vector<int> d(n+1, INF);
    d[0] = -INF;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int j = upper_bound(d.begin(), d.end(), a[i]) - d.begin();
        if (d[j-1] < a[i] && a[i] < d[j])
            d[j] = a[i];
    }

    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (d[i] < INF)
            ans = i;
    }
    return ans;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]